# Unity скрипт не работает на клонированом объекте

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект с прикрипленным к нему скриптом.

```
public GameObject scoreInfo;
static int CurrentScore = 0;

void OnMouseDown() //кнопка мыши нажата
{
    CurrentScore++;
    scoreInfo.GetComponent<Text>().text = CurrentScore.ToString();
}
```

Я клонирую его в Unity 2d.

```
GameObject tmpObj = GameObject.Instantiate(spriteToDuplicate, WorldVector, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Инспектор показывает, что скрипт прикреплен и к оригиналу, и к клонам

[image: img]

но клик по клону ничего не делает, а клик по реальному объекту работает как надо.

В консоли ошибок нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. 
При клонировании ось z была -10;
вот клик и не проходил.

```
tmpObj.transform.position = new Vector3(tmpObj.transform.position.x, tmpObj.transform.position.y, 0);
```